# "\apache-drill-1.6.0\conf was unexpected at this time". Apache installation error

Tags: jdbc, apache-drill

I am trying to install Apache drill on my windows 10 (64 bit) laptop. I followed the instruction from [here](http://drill.apache.org/docs/drill-in-10-minutes/), the official installation document. But when i am running sqlline command `sqlline.bat -u "jdbc:drill:zk=local"` i am getting below error **DRILL_ARGS - " -u jdbc:drill:zk=local"
\apache-drill-1.6.0\conf was unexpected at this time.** I checked online but did not find any solution, please suggest me solution if you faced the same problem in past.

PS: i have set JAVA_HOME environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

After so many hit and trial method, it worked this way: 
Initially my apache installation directory was **C:\Program Files (x86)** but when i changed it to **C:\Users\XYZ** it worked.

Answer (score 0):

That directory should have read/write permission.
Java should be 1.7
Can you cross check these.?